# How to set a multivalued property with SetProps

Tags: c++, mapi

Can anyone provide a simple sample of how to create a multivalued string property(PT_MV_STRING8) and then set it with SetProps? I cannot find any in MSDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `MultiValuePropertyEditor.cpp` in MFCMAPI: https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi/blob/master/UI/Dialogs/Editors/MultiValuePropertyEditor.cpp